# Hide index.php from web site URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm using htaccess rewrite engine to make urls look nice, 
from www.mysite.com/index.php?pag=home to www.mysite.com/pag/home

it works fine with this rule

```
RewriteRule ^pag/([^/]+)$ index.php?pag=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

but when I go to www.mysite.com it redirects me to www.mysite.com/index.php
is there a way to redirect to www.mysite.com/pag/home?

I tried

```
redirect 301 /index.php http://www.mysite.com/pag/home
```

but when i try to go to www.mysite.com the browser gives my "page do not exsist error"

Answer (score 0):

This is the rule that Drupal uses to make it's pretty urls, yours should be extremely similar:
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

Your rule only matches on urls that have pag in them, but you're really wanting to hit every url.

Comment: not really because I've got some independent services on subfolders
so I do not want that when you go to mysite.com/service1 it redirect to www.mysite.com/index.php?pag=service1

Comment: Ah, I understand. You can still use the rule but you'll have to be a little more explicit about how you want it to redirect. Using ^$ instead of ^(.*)$ would target only the empty URL.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in this redirect rule

```
redirect 301 /index.htm http://www.mysite.com/index.php
```